# � Texto con error de codificación �, consulta a MySql desde entity framework

Tags: c#, mysql, mariadb, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

[image: Error en el caracter con tilde]

Buenas tardes compañeros, estoy teniendo el problema que al realizar cualquier consulta a la DB desde el servidor me devuelve un caracter desconocido � donde debería ser una letra con tilde o Ñ, etc..

Igual al caso que se muestra en la imagen de arriba, en un select de provincias que devuelve las respectivas localidades con ese error en las que tienen tilde.

El motor de base de datos que estoy utilizando es `MariaDb` con el conector de `MySql`.

esta es mi ConnStr:

> "server=179.43.xx.xxx;database=sistema;user=root;password=xxxx;SslMode=none;CharSet=utf8mb4" (probé con poner el charset=utf8 solamente) y tampoco ningún resultado positivo :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por si a alguien le sucede, encontré investigando...

La solución es pasar toda la DB y las tablas del motor de BD a UTF8mb4

```
# For each database:
ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

# For each table:
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```